# Motion in the gravitational field along a trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, constrained-dynamics

> A point particle of mass $m$ is moving in the gravitational field along some trajectory which is described by the function $y=y(x)$, which is in a vertical plane and is continuous. Initial conditions are $x=0$ and velocity $v=0$, when $t=0$. How long will it take for the particle to reach the point in the trajectory at $x=b$?

My attempt is: to find the time it takes for the particle to move infinitesimal portion of the curve and integrate that from $a$ to $b$. So at some instance of time $t$=$s$/$v$, where $s$ will be infinitesimal length of the function $(1+y')^{1/2} dx$ and $v$ will be velocity in the previous instance minus gravitational impact $v+gt$.

So my question would be: am I approaching this problem in the right way, if so, how to correctly should I express the velocity, if not, how would you recommend to solve this? I am grateful to any help, detailed analysis is most welcome.

Comment: If $v = 0$ doesn't that mean the particle will fall straight down i.e. along the line $x = 0$?

Comment: Nice point. But for the situation where trajectory is described by some frictionless surface, where starting point is on the slope of the "hill", particle should start moving if the gravity is present.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case your question is a duplicate of [How Long does it take for a roller coaster cart to reach point $x_1$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110399/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about an uniform  gravitational field $\vec{F_G}=${$0,-mg$} than it's possible to write $
y(t)=y_0+v_{0y}-\frac{1}{2}gt^2
$ and $x(t)=x_0+v_{0x}t$ if you impose the initial conditions on $x$
 you shall find that $\forall{t} \rightarrow x(t)=0$ so if $b \ne 0 $ the particle will never reach it beacuse it will just fall along a straight line. Now if the particle it's located on some 2 dimensional manifold $S$ things might change: i'll try to be as clear and concise as possible, forgive me in the case i fail at both. We can start by defining a map from the surface  $S$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$which will translate what happens on the manifold in terms of the coordinates  we knoe how to work with: $\Psi:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ :  {$x_1=x_1(u_1,u_2),x_2=x_2(u_1,u_2)$} where {$u_1,u_2$} is a point on $S$ (actually is another local coordinate system but for our purpose and understanding it's just a point on the surface $S$) than we 
can define the time derivative of the coordinates {$x_i$}$_{i=1,2}$ as $$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=\sum_{m=1,2}\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial u_m}\frac{du_m}{dt}$$ the acceleration will be $$\frac{d^2x_i}{dt^2}=\sum_{m,n=1,2}\frac{\partial^2{x_i}}{\partial u_m \partial u_n}\frac{du_m}{dt}\frac{du_n}{dt}+\frac{d^2u_m}{dt^2}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_m}$$ now  you can write that (under very general and unimportant assumptions) as $$ \frac{d^2x_i}{dt^2}= \frac{d^2u_i}{dt^2}+\sum_{m,n=1,2}\Gamma_{i mn} \frac{du_m}{dt}\frac{du_n}{dt}$$ i.e. the motion on the surface is corrected by a term $\propto \Gamma \dot{u^2}$ which depends on the geometry of it. Now the gravitational field will depend on $x_2$ in the following way $\vec{F_G}=${$0,-mg \sum_{m=1,2}\frac{\partial{x_2}}{\partial{u_m}}$} notice that in the case the surface it's just $\mathbb{R^2}$ it just reduce to the familiar $-mg$ and   you will have $$\ddot{u_1}=-\sum_{m,n=1,2}\Gamma_{1 mn} \frac{du_m}{dt}\frac{du_n}{dt}$$ and $$\ddot{u_2}=-\sum_{m,n=1,2}\Gamma_{2 mn} \frac{du_m}{dt}\frac{du_n}{dt}-g\sum_{m=1,2}\frac{\partial{x_2}}{\partial{u_m}}$$ so really to answer your question now an example it's needed to show how the initial conditions translate on the surface via the map $\Psi$. Ok let's see a "trivial" one: immagine that $$\Psi=\{(x=u+v^2,y=v^3)\}$$ so it's straightforward to see that $$\ddot{x(t)}=\ddot{u}+2\dot{v^2}+2v\ddot{v}=0$$ and $$\ddot{y(t)}=3v^2\ddot{v}+6v\dot{v^2}=-3gv^2$$ since $\vec{F_G}=${$(0,-mg\frac{\partial y}{\partial v})$} by reworking on the equations you might find that $$\ddot{v}=-2\frac{\dot{v^2}}{v}-g$$ and by replacing that in the equation for x we have: $$\ddot{u}=2(\dot{v^2}+gv)$$ with initial conditions $u(0)=-v(0)^2$ and $\dot{u(0)}=-2v(0)\dot{v(0)}$ so now you can see that on that (weird )surface gravty affects both directions due to the strange geomettry of it. Now to answer your question about the time it takesto reach x(\tau)=b, we should first define energy has $$E=\frac{1}{2}m v^2(u_1,u_2)+mgx_2(u_1,u_2)=\frac{1}{2}m(\sum_{i,m,n=1,2}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_m}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_n}\dot{u_m}\dot{u_n})+mgx_2(u_1,u_2)$$ than you can workout the formula until you find $$dt^2=\frac{m}{2}\frac{\sum_{i,m,n=1,2}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_m}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_n}du_m du_n}{(E-mgx_2(u_1,v_1))}$$ and than integrate after you take the square root... I undestand that since it has a very general form it's not very useful at first sight, but if you look at an example it's easily approchable: for istance take the surface {$x_1=x=a(u),x_2=y=b(v)$} (which is a slightly more general case than a curve) than the expression becomes: (notice ' indicates differentiation respect to $u$)$$dt=\pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}\frac{a'(u)^2 du^2+\frac{db(v)}{dv}dv^2}{E-mgb(v)}}$$ now divide and multply by $dv$ and you will obtain $$dt=\pm dv\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}\frac{a'(u)^2 (\frac{du}{dv})^2+\frac{db(v)}{dv}}{E-mgb(v)}}$$ now you should  integrate to time $t*/x(t*)=a(u(t*))=b$, thats the most general and concise case i can make to you(not the easiest by far), hope that helped in some way! (i apologize for the english for is not my mother language)

`

Comment: This might be better if you could add a bit more formatting. For example, you could use `$$ <equation>$$` for a centered equation.

Comment: thank you for the advice i will edit it as soon as i can